# Clicking a dynamically created button appears a popup

Tags: vb.net

I need some help about creating a popup for some imageButtons that I have created dynamically. This is how imageButtons are being created:

small_icon(i) = New ImageButton

small_icon(i).ImageUrl() = "/Images/icon.png"

When I click the image I want to make popup appear. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what an ImageButton is but presumably it has a click event?

So you need to assign an event handler to the buttons event.

Something like:

```
AddHandler small_icon(i).Click, AddressOf ImageButton_Click

Private Sub ImageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
'do something 
End Sub
```